# How to draw camera video as background on IOS using Swift scenekit?

Tags: ios, swift, rendering, augmented-reality, scenekit

I am trying to develop an augmented reality app using swift and scenekit on ios. Is there a way to draw the video captured by the device camera as a background of the scene?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me,

I used `AVFoundation` to capture the video input of the device camera:

```
   let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
   let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

    if let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        var err: NSError? = nil
        if let videoIn : AVCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(videoDevice, error: &err) as? AVCaptureDeviceInput {
            if(err == nil){
                if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoIn as AVCaptureInput)){
                    captureSession.addInput(videoIn as AVCaptureDeviceInput)
                }
                else {
                    println("Failed to add video input.")
                }
            }
            else {
                println("Failed to create video input.")
            }
        }
        else {
            println("Failed to create video capture device.")
        }
    }
    captureSession.startRunning()
```

At this point, based on Apple's documentation of the [`background`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNScene_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNScene/background) property of `SCNScene`, I expected to add the instance of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to an `SCNScene`'s `background.contents`, with something like:

```
   previewLayer.frame = sceneView.bounds
   sceneView.scene.background.contents = previewLayer
```

This changed the background color of my scene from default white to black, but offered no video input. *This may be an iOS bug?.* 
So Plan B. Instead, I added the 'AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer' as a sublayer of a `UIView`'s layer:

```
 previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
 self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
```

I then set an `SCNView` as a subview of that same `UIView`, setting the `SCNView`'s background color to clear:

```
    let sceneView = SCNView()
    sceneView.frame = self.view.bounds
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
```

The device camera's video is now visible as the background of the scene.

I've created a small [demo](https://github.com/judson-douglas/make-camera-sceneview-background/blob/master/DrawsCameraAsBackgoundWithSceneKit/ViewController.swift).

Comment: Did you have any resolution for this? I've hit the same issue and the image from the camera does not appear. The layer does. If I set the background color of the layer, I see the background color, but I don't see the image from the camera at all.

Comment: Thanks for making the demo, Judson :) Super helpful!

Answer (score 5):

As of iOS 11, you can now use an AVCaptureDevice as a material on an object or the scene's background (see "Using Animated Content" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents))

Example:

```
 
    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)!
    scnScene.background.contents = captureDevice
```

Comment: Looks more like a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as the `contents` of a material property (just make sure that you give the layer a bounds).

The scene view has a material property for the background that you can assign the video preview to (assign the layer to the background's contents).

```
var background: SCNMaterialProperty! { get }
```

Comment: A reply a few years later, but are you sure about this? The documentation states that you can, but I, much like the thread creator, cannot get this to work. When I add the layer as the contents of a material property, it camera image does not appear. If I set the layer to be a sublayer of the SCNView, the camera image appears in the layer, but this is not what I want.