# Displaying 3D Model in SceneKit with video in SpriteKit node texture not working

Tags: ios, 3d, sprite-kit, scenekit

I've built a 3D video player and it works just fine. When I go to insert a 3D object (a cube in my case) the cube flickers and is only partially visible (see below).

The code I'm using to insert the cube is pretty straight forward:

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 0.25, height: 0.25, length: 0.25, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.categoryBitMask = StereoCategoryMask.BothEyes.rawValue
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 1.0, y: 0.5, z: 0.5)
```

EDITS:

The video is shot with a 360 camera so I create a sphere (SCNode) and that, for lack of a better term, becomes my world. Inside it the camera is at 0,0,0; I need to keep equal distances from it to prevent barrel distortion.

I'm using an SKNode so I can play the video via a SKVideoNode then I map that onto a SCNode as a texture. It looks something like this: `videoGeomNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = texture` where texture is a SKNode and videoGeomNode is my sphere.

Here is a zoomed in result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[edit: nope, not the answer, see comments; left intact in case it jogs someone's brain for the right answer]

It looks like your camera's Z near clipping limit `zNear` is too far away. Part of your cube is within the camera's frustum, and part is not.

`zNear` defaults to 1.0. Reduce it to something closer to 0.0, or use

```
camera.automaticallyAdjustsZRange = true
```

Comment: I just gave that a try. No luck. If I put the cube on a part with no video then it looks fine; the video is projected onto 1/2 a sphere so the other half (or less depending on the cameras capability) is black / empty.

It seems like, as the video updates at 60 FPS, the cube is redrawing and for some reason glitching. I've had to map the video onto a SceneKit node as a texture; I'm going to try and move the video lower down in the tree hierarchy to see if that has any impact.

Tough to track down :(

Comment: I think it would help if you edit your question and tell us more about the scene and view structure. What sort of object is showing the video? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345737/how-to-draw-camera-video-as-background-on-ios-using-swift-scenekit might be relevant.

Comment: Above I meant I'm using an SKNode so I can play the video via a SKVideoNode then I map that onto a SCNode as a texture. It looks something like this:

`videoGeomNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = texture` where texture is a SKNode.

Comment: Ok this is a somewhat twisted idea but...leave your video setup, sphere, etc as is. Make an SKScene and use it as the `overlaySKScene` for your sceneView. On that overlay, put a single, full screen, SK3DNode, which has your cube or whatever other 3D content you need in front of the video.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had set my zNear to 0.0; zNear can't be 0. Setting it to 0.1 solved my problem.

This is strange because if I put a cube over the video it would flicker while if it put it in blank space it would look fine. I would have thought if it was a zNear issue, then it would affect both cubes in the same way.

Comment: hi jason are you saying you were able to turn a scene into 360 video?

Comment: Yup. Some aspects are a bit tricky. For example, getting stereoscopic barrel distortion working for Cardboard on iOS 8 (its built into ModelIO for 9).

Comment: wow, that's cool! any chance you could share code or techniques? one approach is taking screenshots of the scene from different vantage points then merging all these images into a video, but not sure if that's the optimal approach for rendering a scenekit into a video.

Comment: Unfortunately I wore it for someone else so I can't release it. If I come across some free time I'll do an example on GitHub.

Comment: sure, understood. was your technique very different from taking a screenshot from different camera positions and merging those images into a video?